# response always null restsharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I use restsharp for post data and then return some single value after post completion but it response always get null.

```
public static IRestResponse Services(Object obj)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.1.5/OpManWeb.ServiceHost/api");

            var request = new RestRequest("/SaveExternalOrder/", Method.POST);
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None,
                new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                });
            request.AddParameter("text/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            return response;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check if request built by restsharp look like as you want to.